# converting this Oracle SQL procedure to Mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedures

I tried with online sql to mysql convert tool but it did not help me. Can anyone help me to convert this procedure to mysql version ?

```
create or replace procedure avgmarks is
   cursor c_iamarks is
      select greatest(test1, test2) as a
            ,greatest(test1, test3) as b
            ,greatest(test3, test2) as c
        from iamarks
       where finalia is null
         for update;
   c_a  number;
   c_b  number;
   c_c  number;
   c_sm number;
   c_av number;
begin
   open c_iamarks;
   loop
      fetch c_iamarks
         into c_a
             ,c_b
             ,c_c;
      exit when c_iamarks%notfound;
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C_A || ' ' || C_B || ' ' || C_C);
      if (c_a != c_b)
      then
         c_sm := c_a + c_b;
      else
         c_sm := c_a + c_c;
      end if;
      c_av := c_sm / 2;
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SUM = '||C_SM);
      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AVERAGE = '||C_AV);
      update iamarks
         set finalia = c_av
       where current of c_iamarks;
   end loop;
   close c_iamarks;
end;
/
```

In this i am calculating average of best two marks out of 3 tests and when i call this procedure it should change the values in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can the procedure be replaced with a single update statement?

```
update iamarks
   set finalia = (case
                    when greatest(test1, test2) != greatest(test1, test3) then
                     greatest(test1, test2) + greatest(test1, test3)
                    else
                     greatest(test1, test2) + greatest(test3, test2)
                 end) / 2
 where finalia is null
```

(I have no data so can't confirm that the statement is 100% correct)

Comment: Yes this can be done. I have done this already but i wanted to know how to do convert that sql to mysql dats it.

Comment: Hey can you help me for one more thing? We use MINUS or EXCEPT in oracle but i don't know what to use in mysql for below query  **SELECT E.FNAME, E.LNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE NOT EXISTS((SELECT PNO
FROM PROJECT WHERE DNO=‘5‘)
 MINUS (SELECT PNO
 FROM WORKS_ON
 WHERE E.SSN=SSN));**

Comment: Hi , Since I don't know anything about mysql packages I opted for the SQL option. Whatever works I'd say. Better as a new question to simulate minus operator in MySQL.